# Solaris10/F 9: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: java

I have a java app which runs on Solaris9/CF7 and it is using dom4j library for parsing XML files.
When testing the app on Solaris 10/CF 9 I get the following error:

org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

It looks like the library is not included twice (I removed the library from the instance class path and I got an object instantiation error).

Any ideas?

Thanks.
ags

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classloader issue.  An object created by a class loaded in one classloader *cannot* be cast to the same class loaded in a different classloader.

Answer (score 0):

Watch JENKINS issue - [JENKINS-7666](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7666)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](http://waloua.com/myblog/index.php/caused-by-java-lang-classcastexception-org-dom4j-documentfactory-cannot-be-cast-to-org-dom4j-documentfactory/) will help you.
.

You have same change to do in pom.xml (if you use maven) or in Manifest file(if you don't use maven).